# "No graph definition files were found" - TensorBoard error

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorboard

I used the following code in Pycharm:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

a = tf.constant(value=5, name='input_a')
b = tf.constant(value=3, name='input_b')
c = tf.multiply(a,b, name='mult_c')
d = tf.add(a,b, name='add_d')
e = tf.add(c,d, name='add_e')
print(sess.run(e))

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./tb_graph", sess.graph)
```

Then, I pasted following line to the Anaconda Prompt:

```
tensorboard --logdir=="tb_graph"
```

I tried both with "" and '' as there were proposed: [Tensorboard: No graph definition files were found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153455/tensorboard-no-graph-definition-files-were-found) and it does nothing for me.

> I had similar issue. The issue occurred when I specified 'logdir' folder inside single quotes instead of double quotes. Hope this may be helpful to you.
>   egs: tensorboard --logdir='my_graph' -> Tensorboard didn't detect the graph
>   tensorboard --logdir="my_graph"  -> Tensorboard detected the graph

I checked the code on laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and another one with Win10, so it probably isn't system-based error.

I also tried adding and removing `--host=127.0.0.1` in An Prompt and checking several times both http://localhost:6006/ and http://desktop-.......:6006/.

Still same error:

> No graph definition files were found.
>   To store a graph, create a tf.summary.FileWriter and pass the graph either via the constructor, or by calling its add_graph() method. You may want to check out the graph visualizer tutorial.
>   ....

Please tell me what is wrong in the code/propmp command?

EDIT: On Ubuntu I used the normal terminal, of course.

EDIT2: I used both = and == in command prompt

Comment: it works for me. tensorflow-gpu 1.10.1 tensorboard 1.10.0 ubuntu16.04

Comment: @BugKiller So what do you think I should do? Should I use Anaconda interpreter in PyCharm?

Comment: make sure you indeed generated events file `events.out.tfevents.1535540321???`,  it's 415bytes.  In windows, forwardslash `/ `may be replaced with backwardslash `\`, I'm not sure but you can try. In my env, single quote`'`, double quote `"` or none quote doest matter, tensorboard can handle them correctly.  Oh I knew it,  `--logdir=tb_graph` rather than `--logdir==tb_graph`, **single equal operator** `=`

Comment: @BugKillerThe files have 818 bytes. Is it wrong?

Comment: I have no idea, I may check it in my desktop if you share events file

Comment: @BugKiller Ok. Here is the link: https://ufile.io/4johc It is from directory created by line: writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./new_dir", sess.graph)

Comment: It works, `tensorboard --logdir=tb_graph`

Comment: For me not :( Maybe I don't have something neccesary installed?

Comment: I tried adding 
writer.close()
Still not working.
On Ubuntu and Win10 both...

Comment: weird...  ?? reinstall tensorflow, tensorboard, refresh webpage. btw double equal operator never work for me

Comment: OK. will try soon

Comment: Stiiiiil nooothing....

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! IT WORKS!!! I typed: tensorboard --logdir="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PycharmProjects\try_tb\new1_dir" and in code I changed slash to ".\\new1_dir". Thank you for your help!

Comment: I lose myself totally, `tensorboard --logdir=tb_graph` did work in my win10. whatever relative dir or absolute dir, the dir pointing to events should work. How do you sort out in ubuntu? @mikinoqwert

Comment: On Ubuntu this line worked: --logdir=/home/oem/PycharmProjects/TF_for_MI_1_graph_creating/my_graph. So the full location too, changed \ into / and no parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is:

1) change `"./new1_dir"` into `".\\new1_dir"`

and

2)put full track to file to anaconda propmpt: `--logdir="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PycharmProjects\try_tb\new1_dir"`

Thanks @BugKiller for your help!

EDIT: Working only on Windows for me, but still better than nothing

EDIT2: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 too